# Fail k8s ingress rule when service unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an ingress with something like that in my k8s deployed:

```
rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /path
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: someservice
            port:
              number: 80
     - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: otherservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

The Problem I face is that if `someservice` is not available then this ingress will not return something like a HTTP 503, but will evaluate the next rule and so route to `otherservice`.

Is there some kind of configuration that can be made so that in such cases it will not look for the next rule?

Comment: `pathType: Prefix` for `path: /` will match all request paths. You can check what matches what in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples). Try using `pathType: Exact`

Comment: That would be the solution, thanks. If you could add this as answer I would accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pathType: Prefix` for `path: /` will match all request paths. Try using `pathType: Exact`.

Check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples) to see which `pathType` matches wich `path`.